# $\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial X^2}$ partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm asking for a little help.

I'm trying to resolve this derivative $\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial X^2}$ where $u = f(x,y), x = e^s \cos(t) , y = e^s \sin(t)$

Here's how I try to solve it.

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \cdot \frac{\partial S}{\partial X}$$

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial X} = \frac{1}{e^s \cos t}$$

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \cdot \frac{1}{e^s \cos t}$$

I'm wondering if $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial X^2} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \cdot \frac{1}{e^s \cos t})'$ and how I could do that.

Comment: Is $U$ the same as $u$? Is $X$ the same as $x$? Is $S$ the same as $s$? What is *resole* a typo for?

Comment: sorry, yes U is the same as u and X is the same as x.

Comment: Good. Let me suggest you edit your post so it doesn't have all those inconsistencies. And I still don't know what "resole" is supposed to be.

Comment: I meant resolve.

Comment: Good. So, are you going to do something about all those upper case and lower case letters that should really be the same?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to correct errors in your question, why should anyone else bother to try to answer it?